# App crash: NSInvalidArgumentException in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

I am working a company, and we are doing some application in iOS. Our application good work iOS 7. But I tried XCode simulator iphone 6 or onether. program was give error. I am sharing at below...

```
2014-09-17 08:57:59.972 [783:12416] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.
2014-09-17 08:57:59.976 [783:12416] Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application
2014-09-17 08:58:00.067 [783:12416] -[NSArrayI numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9250fa9e00
2014-09-17 08:58:00.085 [783:12416] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9250fa9e00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4903f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d74dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f49750d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3ef7fc ___forwarding_ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3ef398 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010bc9790e -[UITableViewRowData _updateNumSections] + 84
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010bc98304 -[UITableViewRowData invalidateAllSections] + 69
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010baee343 -[UITableView _updateRowData] + 214
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010bb03107 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 112
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010bb0285d -[UITableView reloadData] + 1316
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010bb0b5a6 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 31
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ba98199 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b6c7f98 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b6bcbbe _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b6bca2e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b62aade _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b62bbea _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010ba1d67d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010ba1e368 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2642
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010ba1cd22 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114aaa2a3 31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3c5abc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK + 12
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3bb805 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3bb5c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3baa06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010ba1c799 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010ba1f550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    27  Polatlƒ± Mersin Borsasƒ±            0x000000010ab89813 main + 115
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ddcc145 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Some thing is wrong with your table view , Check first 4 lines of stack trace

Comment: Which table :)? I didn't find wrong thing in codes:/

Comment: are you using registerForRemoteNotificationTypes in ios 7 ?

Comment: Hi are you adding some viewcontroller.view programmatically which contains the table view?

Comment: Yes I am using registerForRemoteNotificationTypes in ios 7 and I edited for ios 8 now it is work but other problems goings on.

Comment: Please post your UITableViewDelegate and DataSource code, there somewhere is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[As per Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:) `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`: is deprecated in iOS 8 instead you can use `registerForRemoteNotifications` and `registerUserNotificationSettings`.

Comment: Problem of about registerForRemoteNotificationTypes is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit can be seen in the third line from top

```
2014-09-17 08:58:00.067 [783:12416] -[NSArrayI numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9250fa9e00
2014-09-17 08:58:00.085 [783:12416] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9250fa9e00'
```

Put an exception breakpoint in your code first
[image]

Then again run the code and see in which line your exception is getting raised. In your case there seems to be some issue due to which `numberOfSectionsInTableView` (which is a tableView delegate method) is getting called on an NSArray object.

Try with the exception breakpoint and debug and see.
Cheers. Have fun

Comment: I tried breakpoint but program crashed suddenly when opening:(

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller must conform to this protocol `UITableViewDataSource`: there are two methods witch are @required and these you need to implement in your code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

But there are other methods too. You have to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

Take a look if `delegate` & `datasource` are linked to `viewcontroller` in all storyboards or `viewcontroller` .m class

If this is still not the problem. Try with breakpoints and debug the problem...